# How does Spring Security generate a token in Synchronizer Token Pattern solution?

Tags: spring, spring-security

Is anybody know how does Spring generate a token in Spring `Synchronizer Token Pattern` and where it's stored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is generated by the class `org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository` (in spring-security-web jar)

```
private String createNewToken() {
    return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
}
```

It is stored in a user's session.